# How can I replace the parentheses by brackets when using the APA reference style in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

By default, Microsoft Word uses parentheses when using the APA reference style:

[image]

How can I replace the parentheses by brackets when using the APA reference style in Microsoft Word? In the example above, I would like to have `[1]`  instead of  `(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any method that would change those parentheses to some other character. They are inserted by the software and there's no field switch that determines the characters used.

With that said, the citations could be changed to plain text and then the characters can be changed. But it's a one way road if you do that, you can't turn around and make it a citation field once again.